ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H with Yandex Mobile SDK 7.1
I have a working QT Android app with Yandex Mobile SDK 6.4.1.0, but when I try to update it to 7.1.0.0 by replacing
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads-mediation:6.4.1.0'

with
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads-mediation:7.1.0.0'

in my build.gradle I get the following build errors:
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
...
  > Task :mergeExtDexRelease FAILED

  
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
  
  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeExtDexRelease'.
  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
     > Failed to transform inapp-sdk-5.0.0.aar (com.startapp:inapp-sdk:5.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=false, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
        > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\dmitr\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ece0a1adac493ae325ccdc059c741b3b\transformed\jetified-inapp-sdk-5.0.0-runtime.jar.
           > Error while dexing.
     > Failed to transform koin-core-jvm-3.5.3.jar (io.insert-koin:koin-core-jvm:3.5.3) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=false, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
        > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\dmitr\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\219bf1980b2ba19908a72a999814b29b\transformed\jetified-koin-core-jvm-3.5.3.jar.
           > Error while dexing.
     > Failed to transform koin-annotations-jvm-1.3.0.jar (io.insert-koin:koin-annotations-jvm:1.3.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=false, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
        > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\dmitr\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\cc5ef56c144f5f058ee587558b98641d\transformed\jetified-koin-annotations-jvm-1.3.0.jar.
           > Error while dexing.
     > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.9.22.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.22) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=false, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.jvm.environment=standard-jvm, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
        > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\dmitr\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c1da9daaba1aa2ef5cd1c64da66cfa21\transformed\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.22.jar.
           > Error while dexing.
  
  * Try:
  > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  > Run with --scan to get full insights.
  > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
  
  BUILD FAILED in 1m 17s

What do they mean?
As far as I can see, my build.gradle meets all their requirements (about minSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion, etc...).
See full build.gradle content and full build output in my blog post.
There are also a huge amount of D8: Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow. warnings that probably appear when I try a clean build.
I tried to update my Kotlin version:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1'
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
    }
}

but without a success.
EDIT1
Can kotlinOptions affect this?
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

EDIT2:
Updated the namespace:


Gradle 8.3 requires namespace: https://developer.android.com/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace

Finally I was able to built my QT app with Yandex Ad SDK 7.2. Below I provided my builg.gradle file. But it is not clear why kotlinOptions did not compile.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0' //Original QT version was 7.4.1
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.22")
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()

    // IronSource
    maven { url = uri("https://android-sdk.is.com/") }
    // Pangle
    maven { url = uri("https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/pangle") }
    // Tapjoy
    maven { url = uri("https://sdk.tapjoy.com/") }
    // Mintegral
    maven { url = uri("https://dl-maven-android.mintegral.com/repository/mbridge_android_sdk_oversea") }
    // Chartboost
    maven { url = uri("https://cboost.jfrog.io/artifactory/chartboost-ads/") }
    // AppNext
    maven { url = uri("https://dl.appnext.com/") }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    // implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    //See the latest SDK version here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yandex.android/mobileads-mediation
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads-mediation:7.2.0.0'
    // implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:6.2.0'
    // implementation 'com.yandex.ads.mediation:mobileads-google:22.4.0.0'
    // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:7.0.0"
    // From the template
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.10.1'
    //GDPR
    implementation("com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.2.0")
}

android {
    /*******************************************************
    * The following variables:
    * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
    * - androidCompileSdkVersion
    * - qtAndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
    *                   needed to build any Qt application
    *                   on Android.
    *
    * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
    * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
    * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
    *******************************************************/

    //androiddeployqt.exe fails without package attribute in the mainifest.
    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()
    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion
    ndkVersion androidNdkVersion

    // Added while upgrading Gradle plugin to 8.3.
    namespace = "com.domain.myapp"

    // Tried to copy this just in case from Yandex Ad sample, but it does not compile.
    // The error is "Could not find method kotlinOptions() on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension."
    // kotlinOptions {
    //     jvmTarget = "1.8"
    // }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'yandex-ad-src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.incremental = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    // From the template
    // Extract native libraries from the APK
    packagingOptions.jniLibs.useLegacyPackaging true

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    // Do not compress Qt binary resources file
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'rcc'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion qtMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion qtTargetSdkVersion
        ndk.abiFilters = qtTargetAbiList.split(",")
        //For debug builds native-debug-symbols.zip size is 432MB.
        //Use SYMBOL_TABLE to upload debug builds.
        ndk.debugSymbolLevel "FULL"
    }

    //The build type becomes release when we sign the bundle,
    //otherwize the build type is debug with both Debug and RelWithDebInfo.
    //With SYMBOL_TABLE we have .sym in native-debug-symbols.zip and
    //with FULL we have .dbg.
    /*
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //Full debug for uploading production and beta builds.
            ndk.debugSymbolLevel "FULL"
        }

        debug {
            //Small debug info for uploading internal testing builds.
            ndk.debugSymbolLevel "SYMBOL_TABLE"
        }
    }
    */
}

